# Sample code for KeystoneJS 5 custom fields?

Tags: plugins, keystonejs

I'm interested in writing custom fields for KeystoneJS 5.  The documentation is [here](https://www.keystonejs.com/guides/custom-field-types), but I find it somewhat opaque (i.e., not fully explicatory).  Is there sample code available?  I looked in 'demo projects' and 'test projects' in the Keystone repo, but didn't see anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KeystoneJs custom fields are poorly documented and not easily accessible. in fact the whole concept of writing the whole custom field may be overkill.

here is the example one core team member has put copied form the test-project. - https://github.com/MadeByMike/keystone-custom-field/blob/7caf0139c189eadda1884a86073c6945bdd6ff05/index.js#L15

this is what you need to do:
 1. you need to create a folder for the field
 2. you can copy the Text field implementation to start with
 3. there index.js file must export specific object (default export) like this ( I have added some comment for each line)

```
{
  type: 'Stars', // name of the implementation
  implementation: Stars, // implementation itself
  views: { // all views are required you can copy the implementation from Text field)
    Controller: Integer.views.Controller, // it is using controller from Integer field type
    Field: require.resolve('./views/Field'), // field which goes into edit page or create dialog
    Filter: Integer.views.Filter, // this adds filters in the list page
    Cell: require.resolve('./views/Cell'), // view for list page where you usually see the text, for Relationship it is rendered as link.
  },
  adapters: {
    mongoose: MongoIntegerInterface, // mongoose adapter specific inplementation
    knex: KnexIntegerInterface, // knex adapter specific implementation,.
  },
}
```

4. create views for each type (Field, Filter, Cell etc.)
5. import the field (default import) in the schema definition and use it like regular field. any custom option is passed on to the custom implementation.

Comment: I looked at the sample code in the link above (https://github.com/MadeByMike/keystone-custom-field/blob/7caf0139c189eadda1884a86073c6945bdd6ff05/index.js#L15), -- how does one know what props are passed to the views?

Comment: this is where it passes on the settings to admin-ui - https://github.com/MadeByMike/keystone-custom-field/blob/7caf0139c189eadda1884a86073c6945bdd6ff05/custom-field/Stars/Implementation.js#L5